# Is there a way to get source of duplicate resource?

Tags: puppet

I'm getting an error like this when running `puppet agent -t`:

```
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Cannot alias File[sources.list] to ["/etc/apt/sources.list"] at /var/puppet/git/autopush/apt/manifests/init.pp:114; resource ["File", "/etc/apt/sources.list"] already declared at /var/puppet/git/autopush/profiles/manifests/apt/v16_04/sources_list.pp:5
```

But I have no way of telling which manifest is it that is trying to declare a duplicate resource(apart from the `/var/puppet/git/autopush/apt/manifests/init.pp:114`, but that is the final one). Is there a way to show manifest "stack" when running `puppet agent -t`?

Comment: The error message in your question states the location of both declarations.

Comment: I will correct my question because I now see it's flaw. Thank you. I was after some sort of manifest stack, rather than displaying only the final one.

Comment: Are you asking what other class/DRT is declaring/including/etc. the resources in question? If so, are you using Puppet Enterprise, PuppetDB, Foreman, etc?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I'm using Foreman. Yes, I would like to have the complete "chain" of manifests that included this `File[sources.list]`. There probably was Manifest A that included B that included C and then C finally included the `/var/puppet/git/autopush/apt/manifests/init.pp`

Comment: Ok Foreman will provide that information about the stack of resource declaration. It should be viewable in its interface.

Comment: It is, @MattSchuchard. I checked older executions and I could see the other manifest for some other errors. But for this specific one, the message is exactly the same. Could it be that that `/var/puppet/git/autopush/apt/manifests/init.pp` manifest git somehow included "implicitly"? Sorry, I'm new to puppet and some of the things I say might not make sense.

Comment: Yes but it would still be included in the catalog.